# Stylelint rule to enforce selector and attribute on same line

Tags: css, stylelint

Is there a [stylelint rule](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules) that can enforce a selector and attribute to be on the same line if there is only one attribute.

For example, this would error:

```
.foo{
  color: #111;
}
```

Because we want it to look like this:

```
.foo{ color: #111; }
```

Note, if there are multiple attributes then they should be on their own lines, for example:

```
.foo{
  color: #111;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a stylelint rule that can enforce a selector and attribute to be on the same line if there is only one attribute.

Not yet.

The [`declaration-block-single-line-max-declarations`](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/declaration-block-single-line-max-declarations) rule will get you halfway there. For example:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "declaration-block-single-line-max-declarations": 1
  }
}
```

Will disallow:

```
.foo{ color: #111; display: block; }
```

But allow:

```
.foo{ 
  color: #111;
}
```

What you need is a "declaration-block-multi-line-min-declarations" rule. You can create one as a [stylelint plugin](https://stylelint.io/developer-guide/rules). However, I believe such a rule should be built into stylelint. You can [open an issue and request](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/new?template=REQUEST_A_FEATURE.md) to add the rule to stylelint.

You'll then be able to enforce your code style with:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "declaration-block-single-line-max-declarations": 1,
    "declaration-block-multi-line-min-declarations": 2
  }
}
```